# Refresh android PreferenceFragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-preferences

I have a `CheckBoxPreference` in a `FragmentPreference`. When the user active the check box, I check if an application is installed and if not, I reset the preference on false and I open the *Play Store* to download the app.

Basically all works fine, but I have an issue to refresh the UI. Indeed, even if I set the preference on false before opened the *Play Store*, when the user come back, the box is checked (the fragment has just been paused and resumed so the preference value is ignored).

Is there a way to "refresh" the activity or the fragment?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Make your PreferenceFragment implement the [OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener.html) interface.

In `onCreate()`, you can read the preference value and set the UI accordingly.  For instance:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Load the preferences from an XML resource.
    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.shakesql_app_prefs);

    // Initialize pref summary label.

    // Get a reference to the application default shared preferences.
    SharedPreferences sp = getPreferenceScreen().getSharedPreferences();

    // Read the current preference value.
    String listVal =
            sp.getString(getString(R.string.preference_font_size_key),
                    getString(R.string.preference_font_size_default));

    // Look up the textual description corresponding to the
    // preference value and write it into the summary field.
    String listDesc = descriptionFromPref(
            listVal, 
            getResources().getStringArray(
                    R.array.preference_font_size_values), 
                    getResources().getStringArray(
                            R.array.preference_font_size_labels)
                    );
    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(listDesc)) {
        ListPreference listPref =
                (ListPreference) findPreference(getString(R.string.preference_font_size_key));
        listPref.setSummary(listDesc);
    }
}
```

Then, in `onSharedPreferenceChanged()`, update the UI.

```
public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String key) {
    Preference pref = findPreference(key);
    if (pref instanceof ListPreference) {
        // Update display title
        // Write the description for the newly selected preference 
        // in the summary field.
        ListPreference listPref = (ListPreference) pref;
        CharSequence listDesc = listPref.getEntry();
        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(listDesc)) {
            pref.setSummary(listDesc);
        }
    }        
}
```

Here's a code snippet from the AdvancedPreferences sample in API Demos to force the value of a checkbox preference.

```
// Toggle the value of mCheckBoxPreference.
if (mCheckBoxPreference != null) {
            mCheckBoxPreference.setChecked(!mCheckBoxPreference.isChecked());
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. I use `onSharedPreferenceChanged` too, but `sharedPreferences.edit().putBoolean("key", false).commit();` don't refresh the UI, that is my issue. (As contrary of `setSummary()` for example).

Comment: Shame on me I didn't think to cast the `Preference` to `CheckBoxPreference`. Thank you very much for your time.